# Change click event for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the button (temperature toggling) for browsers which width is less than 400px. Instead i want to touch a div to toggle temperature. I wrote this code but it does not work. "touchTemp" is id of the containing div.

```
if (window.innerWidth < 400) {
  document.getElementById("touchTemp").addEventListener("click",
    function(e) {
      console.log("Screen width is less than 400px");
      var text = $('#temperature').text();
      if (text.slice(-1) === "F") {
        $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + " C" + "°");
      } else {
        $("#temperature").html(tempFahrenheit + " F");
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    });
} // end of "if statement"
```

[image]

Outlined blue div is the area to be touched to toggle temperature.

[CodePen Project Link](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/OXAPKm)

Comment: Why remove the button and add a div? Instead, just style the button. CSS media-query around the rule, and you're set to go. No JavaScript required. Always works, and if styling would fail for whatever reason, you still got a working button, which seems to be the most important part.

Comment: Good idea actually i will take that into consideration.

Comment: @Rajesh That’s not true. Mobile devices do have a `click` event.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just add the touch handler along with the click for completeness and ease of testing.

```
var theElement = document.getElementById("touchTemp");

theElement.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
theElement.addEventListener("touchend", myFunction, false);

function myFunction(e) {
  console.log("Screen width is less than 400px");
  var text = $('#temperature').text();
  if (text.slice(-1) === "F") {
    $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + " C" + "°");
  } else {
    $("#temperature").html(tempFahrenheit + " F");
  }

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Add an onload event handler! getElementById just works when the page is loaded